# How to send dumpfile to email using NBUG

Tags: nbug

I have a windows application that I would like to configure to use NBug to send error reports via email.
I configured in program.cs as per the nbug documentation but dumpfile is creating no email is sent or received?

Comment: Please add configuration, logs etc.

Comment: NBug.Settings.AddDestinationFromConnectionString("Type=Mail;From=xxxx@yyy.com;Port=587 ;SmtpServer=smtp-mail.outlook.com;To=xxxxx@yyyy.com;UseAttachment=True;UseAuthentication=True;UseSsl=True;Username=xxxxx@yyyy.com;Password=Secure;");

Answer (score 0):

Configuration tool has a test mode. You can use it to test your configuration (read the instructions in the docs to learn how to use it).